# Service Stack API Explorer - how to customize the landing page?

Tags: .net, servicestack

I created a new ServiceStack (v. 6.11) project using the "x" tool, as suggested in the documentation:
https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice#step-2-selecting-a-template

The API explorer (https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer) is automatically enabled and working under URL `https://localhost:5001/ui/`. The docs mention that it is possible to override some parts of it: https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer#override-built-in-components

My question is - is it possible to modify the landing page? I would like to replace the "Welcome to" with my own custom HTML content. [image: Service Stack UI explorer landing page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find the solution. It is based on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/modules/ui/components/Welcome.mjs

So that file has to be placed like this:
[image]

Which results in

[image]

I wish that was better documented :(

Comment: In addition to [API Explorer customizations](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer#api-docs) which include how to [override built-in components](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer#override-built-in-components), you can also look at [customization options for Locode](https://docs.servicestack.net/locode/custom-components#example) which is built on the same technology.